# Coupon code validation

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I am trying to modify coupon code functionality.  I have got a situation where I am not able to find where a coupon code is validated. I have searched the entire code base. Can anyone point me in right direction?

> I am trying to apply Multiple Coupon codes.

Comment: Can you specify what you are actual try to do?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, the question updated.

Comment: your requirement is to apply multiple coupen code, right?

Comment: yes, the same functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the class `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility` located at the `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Utility.php`. Coupon code validation starts in the method `canProcessRule()` where it can mark the rule as invalid if coupon code does not match conditions like usage per customer etc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is quite complex. I will try to provide some hints hopefully i will save somebody's time:

First, coupons (from view cart page) are submitted to *Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost* **execute()** method. Coupons from the checkout page are posted to APIs via ajax, check the actual url in browser's network tab from Tools.

After this, the situation gets complicated :-) It starts from

- *vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/RulesApplier.php* **applyRules()**

```
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    if (!$this->validatorUtility->canProcessRule($rule, $address)) {
    ...
```

and canProcessRule() goes to

- *vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Utility.php* **canProcessRule** - method which checks if a rule can be applied for a specific address/quote/customer

The **applyRules()** method from *RulesApplier.php* also has the following code:

```
$rule->getActions()->validate($childItem)
```

which takes us to

- *vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/Condition/Combine.php* **_isValid()**. This method validates the coupon's conditions, and it's the starting point in the validation process. It has this line of code

```
$validated = $cond->validate($entity);
```

which actually goes into the next file/method:

- *vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Found.php* **validate()**. This method validates individual coupon's conditions and uses the following code

```
$validated = $cond->validate($item);
```

which goes to the next file/method:

- *vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php* **validate()** which validates a product rule condition. This validates things related to products - like categories and price and through this code

```
return parent::validate($product);
```

goes into the MOST IMPORT VALIDATION part which is in the file

- *vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/Condition/Product/AbstractProduct.php* **validate()** which validates product attributes.

If you think this can't get more complicated, you're wrong, it goes further down, but you get the idea.